# Python - cannot import name sqldf

Tags: python, pandas

I keep getting the error `cannot import name sqldf`

I use the following

```
import pandas
import pandasql
from pandasql import sqldf
```

My python version is 2.7 and up to date, also pandas and pandasql are up to date.

I installed pandasql with `pip install -U pandasql`

Any idea why i get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the version shown in `pip show pandasql`?

Comment: It shows Version: 0.6.2, Location: c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandasql-0.6.2-py2.7.egg

Comment: Just curious -- why are you importing pandasql *and* importing sqldf from pandasql? Shouldn't the first import already take care of sqldf?